# R keras tensorflow.problem Python 3.6 instead of 3.8

Tags: r, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I tried so many time and different solutions to use Keras and Tensorflow in R but each time it is the same problem. Python 3.6 is used instead of 3.8, and so I cannot run models. Why in the folder r-reticulate it is Python 3.6?

If someone knows how to solve it, or to select others Python version that is in the folder r-miniconda it would be great.

```
> reticulate::py_config()
python:         C:/Users/Mezeix/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/python.exe
libpython:      C:/Users/Mezeix/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/python36.dll
pythonhome:     C:/Users/Mezeix/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate
version:        3.6.10 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, May  7 2020, 19:46:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:          C:/Users/Mezeix/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/Lib/site-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  1.19.1
```

I tried these 3 solutions with no success:

```
original_path <- Sys.getenv("PATH")
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste("C:/Users/Mezeix/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/", original_path, sep = ":"))
library(reticulate)
reticulate::py_config()



options(reticulate.conda_binary = "C:/Users/Mezeix/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/")
library(reticulate)
reticulate::py_config()

original_path <- Sys.getenv("PATH")
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste("C:/Users/Mezeix/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/", original_path, sep = ":"))
library(reticulate)
reticulate::py_config()
```